# Nested struct in C saying "warning: comparison between pointer and integer"

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a nested struct defined as follows:

```
/* Buffering incoming CAN messages */
union CANDATA   // Unionize for easier cooperation amongst types
{
    unsigned long long ull;
    signed long long   sll;
    u32        ui[2];
    u16        us[4];
    u8     uc[8];
    u8     u8[8];
    s32        si[2];
    s16        ss[4];
    s8         sc[8];
};
struct CANRCVBUF        // Combine CAN msg ID and data fields
{ //                               offset  name:     verbose desciption
    u32 id;         // 0x00 CAN_TIxR: mailbox receive register ID p 662
    u32 dlc;        // 0x04 CAN_TDTxR: time & length p 660
    union CANDATA cd;   // 0x08,0x0C CAN_TDLxR,CAN_TDLxR: Data payload (low, high)
};
struct CANRCVTIMBUF     // CAN data plus timer ticks
{
    union LL_L_S    U;  // Linux time, offset, in 1/64th ticks
    struct CANRCVBUF R; // CAN data
};
```

My variable is the declared as follows:

```
static struct CANRCVTIMBUF* pfifo1; // Pointer to CAN driver buffer for incoming CAN msgs, high priority
```

I think I am wrapping my head around what is happening with the pointers here, but what I am trying to do is access the id value of pfifo1:

```
if(&pfifo1->R.id == 0x44200000) { // Message to toggle blue led
    toggle_led(15);
}
```

This gives me the warning `warning: comparison between pointer and integer` for that line. My thought was that `&pfifo1->R` would get me the `CANRCVBUF` struct from which I could access the id using the `.`... unfortunately doesn't seem to be the case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
&pfifo1->R.id
```

That results in a pointer to int, i.e., it is the address of `R.id`.  You don't need the address of operator if you want to compare `R.id` to `0x44200000`

```
if(pfifo1->R.id == 0x44200000)
```

Remember; `->` dereferences the pointer, so no need for `&` (not that you would need it anyway), and `->` has a higher precedence than `&`.

Answer (score 2):

You're close. `&pfifo1->R.id` will get you the address of the `id` field, but you want to compare its value. To do so, simply remove the address-of operator (`&`).

```
if(pfifo1->R.id == 0x44200000) { // Message to toggle blue led
    toggle_led(15);
}
```